# Prevent Image & Text from Overlapping

Tags: html, css

I have a slider that is encased in a div. Each element is placed within this div, and the image is set as the div's background. To the left I have an image and to the right I have a header and text and a call to action button.

I want the image to be immediately left of the text. If I set the width of the text to something smaller, when the page is viewed on mobile, the image will make the text unreadable. What implementations in HTML & .css would you consider to be the best/simplest way to make this work?

[image: Redering of Design Issue]

```css
.slide-email-thread {
    background: url("http://4.imimg.com/data4/YP/FD/MY-13642581/hp-laptop-500x500.jpg") no-repeat bottom left;
    background-size: contain;
    height: 500px;
    width: 120%;
    bottom: 8px;
    left: 16px;
}
.email-thread-header{
  font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}
.email-thread-text {
  color:#FFFFFF;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  width: 100%;
}
.email-thread-btn-link {
  width: 50%;
}
.email-thread-button {
  
}
.email-thread-btn {
    border: 2px solid #FFFFFF !important;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease, color 0.5s ease, border 0.5s ease;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #FFFFFF !important;
    padding: 1% 1%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30%;
}
.email-thread-btn:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#F8981D !important;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease, color 0.5s ease, border 0.5s ease;
    background-color: #FFFFFF !important;
}
.slide-content {
  margin:0px auto; 
  width:100%;
  line-height:1.1
  margin-top: -30px;
  font-weight:400; 
  margin-bottom:30px; 
  width:75%;
  text-align:left;
  padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient-bg-email-thread slide">
<div class="slide-email-thread">
<div class="slide-content">
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQhhrwa3eP_qIPbSl9jCJe1JrAN7ahuI0IozBVF89fLJH0X7izl" style="padding-top: 20px;"/>
<div class="email-thread-header">Introducing My Site</div>
<div class="email-thread-text">My text is here & it is overlappng.</div>
<div class="email-thread-link"><a class="home_slide-banner email-thread-btn" href="example.com" target="_blank">CHECK IT OUT</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The slider must be a div, Would it be better to place the image simply inside the div as opposed to making it a background within the div slider?

For it to appear okay on mobile, would it be best to add an opacity to the image to the text can be readable? Unsure what the easier thing to do is here.

JS Fiddle Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/b63xwb0z/

Comment: Can you provide a working demo please?

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle or something to make this easier to read?

Comment: I created a jsFiddle using your code (just changed the image to have one working), but maybe there is missing CSS, the behavior isn't what intended and it won't like that (I mean, the bug you state is not there neither the proper behavior). https://jsfiddle.net/tjvL10f7/

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the feedback! Here is a JS Fiddle! https://jsfiddle.net/b63xwb0z/ @MichaelCoker

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b63xwb0z/ @AndreiTumbar I made a Jsfiddle, sorry for the trouble

Comment: @MasterDJon I am so sorry, there was indeed missing code. This is kinda' what it looks like. It is confined to a small size but generally the text is on the left, but it is still overlapping. I really just need help conceptualizing what to do with mobile screens. Should the image not be the background inside the div and instead be an image placed right placed on the div?

https://jsfiddle.net/b63xwb0z/

Comment: I think the PhilD's answer seems OK.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest some responsive styling. Place all of the elements that you wish to be positioned to the side of your image in a containing div and use media queries in your css to restyle the image and content sections. Also, avoid inline styling where possible in order to avoid headaches in the future.

Try something like this within your slide

HTML

```
<div class="slide-image">
    <img src="logo-image.png"/>
</div>

<div class="slide-content">
    <div class="slider-header">
        Introducing My Site
    </div>

    <div class="slider-text">
        Welcome to the hmpg slider with content in it.
    </div>

    <div class="button-link">
        <a class="slider-button-cta" href="example.com" target="_blank">LEARN MORE</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slide-image,
.slide-content
{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.slide-image img
{
    padding-top: 20px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) /* I picked 600px arbitrarily */
{
    .slide-image
    {
        width: 14em; /* I picked 14em arbitrarily */
    }

    .slide-content
    {
        width: calc(100% - 14em);
    }
}
```

You can start reading about responsive web design [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Phil D. I didnt fully build out the media queries for responsive yet because the desktop version is still not positioned the way it needs to be. I was trying to get the desktop version on par first and then was hoping to adapt it to mobile without doing too much. But being open to the fact that it is possible that my current format may have to change to fit to mobile. It was just hard to conceptualize what should happen with that image and text. Ill try out your recommendation in the morning.

Comment: The advantage of media queries is that they still work on desktop. When the user resizes their window to above the 600px I specified, the conditional styling is used. Some argue that developing for mobile first is the best approach, but ultimately it's up to you. You could reverse this to be desktop first. If you use calc in the width of .slide-content you should be able to avoid the overflow issue. Alternatively you could look into [display: table](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/#display-table) or [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/flex/) solutions :)

Comment: This is an excellent point. Thinking about mobile first definitely would have not put me in this position! Going back to the initial conceptualization, would you say that having the background inside the main div is okay, or do you think this would have been easier overall if I simply placed the image as a stand-alone item inside the div itself, rather than it being the background of the div? Or does it not really matter?

Comment: The general rule, for accessibility purposes, is that if an image is for _decoration only_ it should be a background image. All other images should be an img tag. Read up on image accessibility [here](https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/images/).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with an img element contained within another element that has a background-image. This looks cluttered to me. I'd suggest having a content element with sub-elements that group your content. You can then layout these groupings however you like. You could set the containing element to _position: relative_ and then set absolute positions for _.slider-image_ and _.slider-content_ if you like? Just throwing more options out there for you to play around with.

Comment: Another gotcha to look out for is cross-browser compatibility. Chrome browsers will handle _background-size: contain_ exactly how I would want, but I've found Firefox does and IE do not.

Answer (score 0):

I insist you not to put image as background Especially when you are displaying image at left and displaying header, paragraph on right because you need to the more preventive measures for image not go under text.

The Best/simplest way would be to use `<img src="" />` tag in html.

Here is the Code with PC , mobile view for iphone 6 plus [max-device-width:414px] and  iphone 6 [max-device-width:375px] :

HTML :

```
<div class="gradient-bg slide">
        <div class="slide-hmpg">
            <img src="current-ac-banner.jpg" alt="slide image" class="slide-image" /> <!--ADD YOUR IMAGE HERE -->
            <div class="slide-containing-content">
                <div class="slider-header">Introducing My Site</div>
                <div class="slider-text">Welcome to the hmpg slider with content in it.</div>
                <div class="button-link"><a class="slider-button-cta" href="" target="_blank">LEARN MORE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

css

```
img.slide-image{ /*Added This class for image*/
        width:400px;
        height:auto;
        float:left;
        margin-right:20px;
    }

    .gradient-bg { /* gradient bg inside of slider, truncated */
        background: #F8981D; /* Old browsers */
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #F8981D 0%, #B1792A 45%);
        width:100%;
        height:660px;
    }

    .slider-header{ /* Overlap issue */
      font-family: "Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
      padding-top: 20px;
      padding-bottom: 20px;
      font-size: 40px;
      width: 95%;
      margin: 0;    
    }
    .slider-text {  /* Overlap issue */
      font-size: 15px;
      margin: 0 auto 30px;
      width: 100%;
    }


    .button-link {
      width: 50%;
      float:left; /*Added This*/
    }


    .slider-button-cta { /* overlap issue on mobile */
        border: 2px solid #000000 !important;
        border-radius: 3px;
        background-color: transparent !important;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        padding: 1% 1%;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 30%;
    }


    /*FOR IPHONE 6 PLUS */
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 414px) and (orientation: portrait){
        img.slide-image{ /*Added This class for image*/
            width:100%;
            height:auto;
            float:center;
        }

        .button-link {
            width:100%;
            margin-left:10px;
        }

        .slider-header, .slider-text{
            margin-left:10px;
        }
    }

    /*FOR IPHONE 6 */
    @media screen and (max-device-width: 375px) and (orientation: portrait){
        .button-link {
            width:420px;
            margin-left:10px;
        }
    }
```